# Multi-Layered SWF with dynamic animation

Tags: apache-flex, animation, flash

I'm new to Flash and I trying to do something as following:
I need the ability run several layers of animation (image sequences) in a single file (ex. SWF) which will be loaded and accessed dynamically by Flex - I need to change the content (image sequence) in runtime in order to customize my animation.

What would be the best approach in this case?

Is it the correct direction?

Should I consider creating a SWF for each animation and load it dynamically into my layered SWF?

Answer (score 0):

When you say you need to adjust the image sequence, do you mean customise the order of individual frames, or simply select between a selection of set sequences?

If it's the former, the answer will be a bit more in-depth, if it's the latter and there aren't too many you're probably best off exporting as SWFs, or even as a video file to compress them, then loading them in dynamically. If they're small enough not to add significant weight to your SWF, you could export them as MovieClips in a SWC and create instances of them directly in the code without having to load them in.

Hope this helps (sorry if any of the above is confusing!) - could you give a bit more detail on what you're trying to achieve?